# Logwatch shows entries that do not exist

Tags: 14.04, logwatch

Logwatch shows

```
A total of 13 possible successful probes were detected (the following URLs
 contain strings that match one or more of a listing of strings that
 indicate a possible exploit):

    /wp-content/themes/NativeChurch/download/download.php?file=../../../../wp-config.php HTTP Response 301 
....
```

I enter

```
find / -name "NativeChurch"
```

I get zero results.

I enter

```
find / -name "wp-config.php"
```

I get two results.

```
/var/www/vhosts/result1/httpdocs/wp-config.php
/var/www/vhosts/result2/httpdocs/wp-config.php
```

I enter

```
cd /var/www/vhosts/result1/httpdocs
cd wp-content/themes/NativeChurch
```

I get

```
No such file or directory
```

I enter

```
cd /var/www/vhosts/result2/httpdocs
cd wp-content/themes/NativeChurch
```

I get

```
No such file or directory
```

Why can I not find the file? The server is the right one. The logwatch is current.

EDIT:

```
find / -name NativeChurch -type d
```

I get zero results.